# Problem with using PHPQuery

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom, phpquery

I trying to use PHPquery to scrape web-page (free-lance.ru)

Equiv code in Simple HTML Dom is working:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$shd = str_get_html($html);

$projects = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($shd->find('.project-preview') as $work){
    $projects[$i]['name'] = $work->find('h3', 0)->children(1)->plaintext;
    $i++;
}
```

But i need it in PHPQuery.

I tried to use something like:

```
include('phpQuery.php');

$pq = phpQuery::newDocument($html);

foreach ($pq->find('.project-preview') as $work){
        echo 'wow';
}
```

But it doesn't working... sizeof($pq->find('.project-preview')) is 0

I will be very thankful for any help.

Comment: Two questions: If you have it working in simple_dom, why do you need PHPQuery? And what have you tried in PHPQuery this far?

Comment: I need to test effectivity of PHPQuery

Comment: If you're sure it's a .html file, why don't you use `newDocumentHTML` instead of `newDocument` ?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same question! So answering for the next visitors to this question.

Simple HTML Dom has some memory leak problems. You have to be very carefull when you are 'cloning' object by its selector. Avoid it!

With phpQuery it is only one command which clears all, as far as I know.

```
phpQuery::unloadDocuments();
```

I tested phpQuery. Which looks like it has NO memory leaks. Also very very low memory usage. Only 4 kB on a file of 90 kB. So it looks like it parses real-time and does not have the document in memory. At least that is what I found, I could be wrong.

Also tried creating 20-30 docs and use unload every time, no memory increase... nice!

Here's me answer:

```
include('phpQuery.php');

$pq = phpQuery::newDocument($html);

$projects = array();
$i = 0;

foreach ($pq['.project-preview'] as $work) {
    // iteration returns PLAIN dom nodes, NOT phpQuery objects
    $pqwork = pq($work);

    $projects[$i]['name'] = $pqwork['div']->eq(1)->text();
    // Unfortunately pq($work)['div']->eq(1)->text(); does not work

    $i++;
}

phpQuery::unloadDocuments();
```

Would be nice if there we're some more examples of the basic things! Good project, bad documentation. Or at least I couldn't find the documentation which explain text() function for example.

Benchmarks estimates:

- phpQuery is ~ 3,5 faster in loading documents.
- Simple HTML Dom looks ~ 30% faster in selecting :(

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint about unloadDocuments(), my script was using so much RAM because simply unsetting didn't free up the memory, but after calling $mydom->unloadDocument() all memory is cleaned up properly. They should add a destructor to phpQuery so it does this automatically...

Comment: Great to hear! :) Yes, memory management could be better indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. This basically equivalient code ran just fine for me.

```
$q = phpQuery::newDocument('                                                    
<html>                                                                          
<body>                                                                          
<div class="findme">Lorem ipsum</div><div class="ignoreme">dolor sit amet</div> 
</body>                                                                         
</html>                                                                         
'                                                                               
);                                                                              

foreach($q->find('.findme')  as $tag) {                                         
    echo 'Found: '.$tag->tagName."(".$tag->getAttribute('class').")\n";         
}
```

Result:

> Found: div(findme)

So, the question becomes:

- Are you getting any errors? (and is error_reporting turned on? What about display_errors?)
- What does your HTML look like?

**Update:**

From your comment below, it turns out you're trying to open a html file with `newDocment()`. That just won't work. You have to use `newDocumentFile()` - or read the file contents yourself, and then use `newDocument()`, passing what you read to phpQuery.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't working with offline txt file... I usend free-lance.txt with content from the site... But... maybe cause is encoding? file is in utf-8 but site in cp1251?

Comment: if it's a HTML document, don't name the file `.txt` - that's just confusing. Also, to read from a file (as opposed to a string), use `phpQuery::newDocumentFile()`, not `newDocument()`. This is mentioned on http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Basics.